# Proper way to merge two streams with independent & equal timeouts in RxJava

Tags: android, timeout, observable, rx-java

I would like to know how to best combine two streams that each have independent timeouts of the same duration in RxJava without causing a crashing bug.

In RxJava, if you run the following code, you will cause a crashing exception:

```
val testObs = Single.fromCallable {
    Thread.sleep(10000)
}.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .timeout(5000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .timeout(5000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .test()

testObs.awaitTerminalEvent()
```

This is because both of those `timeouts` execute on the [`computation`](https://www.codota.com/web/assistant/code/rs/5c780d2fdf79be0001ddeeb2#L2473) thread, which [is or can be multi-threaded](https://android.jlelse.eu/rxjava-schedulers-what-when-and-how-to-use-it-6cfc27293add). One of the timeouts will succeed and shut down the stream, the second will throw a crashing exception:

> io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with.

Obviously one obvious solution is not to attach two timeouts of the same duration to a single stream.

However, lets imagine a simple `Api` class, that defines two methods:

```
  fun getNewMessages: Single<List<Messsage>>
  fun getUserProfileInfo: Single<Profile>
```

In your code, pretend you have separate `Activity`s that each call these methods independently; you also have a `StartupActivity` that calls both of these methods, but uses [`Single.zip`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) to merge each of those operations so it can essentially pre-fetch the data and have the app configured and ready for the user prior to the call to `finish()` of the startup splash screen. The implementation of each of those methods uses a common networking class that applies a standard `.timeout` value of 30 seconds.

Unfortunately, if there is a networking issue that causes both of those methods to stall beyond their default `.timeout` values, a `Single.zip` that combines each of those network operations will crash.

Thus, is there a recommended pattern for combining multiple signals each with independent timeout values that may be equal and thus fire simultaneously? If we take the approach "no adding timeouts unless you are the final consumer", that will end up with a lot of copy-pasted `.timeout(30, TimeUnit.SECOND)` calls throughout our code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `UndeliverableException` exception is wrapping the :

> java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: The source did not signal an
>   event for 5000 milliseconds and has been terminated

You're right about the `timeout` operator, by default it is executed in the computation scheduler. Chaining them with the same duration will lead to a non deterministic result. Sometimes the first one will fire the `TimeoutException` sometimes the second one.

You can avoid the `zip` operator to crash by using one of the `onErrorX` methods and emit a special instance of the combined object. Ex :

```java
long CONFIGURED_TIMEOUT = 300L;

Single<String> getNewMessages = Single.fromCallable(() -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return "";
}).timeout(CONFIGURED_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

Single<Long> getUserProfileInfo = Single.fromCallable(() -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return 1L;
}).timeout(CONFIGURED_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);


TestObserver<String> testObs = Single.zip(
        getNewMessages,
        getUserProfileInfo,
        (a, b) -> a + " --- " + b)
        .onErrorResumeNext(Single.just("Special item"))
        .test();

testObs
        .awaitCount(1)
        .assertNoErrors()
        .assertValue("Special item");
```

Or, you can use a `Maybe` to emit an `empty` and doing some side effect processing when you receive an error :

```java
TestObserver<String> testObs = Maybe.zip(
        getNewMessages.toMaybe(),
        getUserProfileInfo.toMaybe(),
        (a, b) -> a + " --- " + b)
        .doOnError(th -> System.out.println("Do side effect error handling"))
        .onErrorResumeNext(Maybe.empty())
        .test();
```

Be careful with the order, `doOnError` will receive nothing if you put `onErrorResumeNext` before it.